# Automatic alias pattern to accommodate node hierarchy and menu items

Tags: path-aliases

I've got a site where some parent menu items are nodes and some are dynamically generated with views and panels. I'm using Node Hierarchy and Pathauto to manage the structure but I'm having some difficulty with Url replacement patterns.

If the parent item is a page, this pattern gives me the correct Url:

```
[node:nodehierarchy:parent:menu-link:?]/[node:title]
```

but it doesn't work when the parent item is a view. Likewiswe, if the parent item is a view, this pattern gives the correct Url:

```
[node:menu-link:parent:url:path]/[node:title]
```

but it doesn't work when the parent item is another node. I guess I could solve the problem by having separate content types for pages whose parent is a menu item and pages whose parent is another node. Or by using menu items for everything, or maybe by writing a custom module. But before I take any of these steps I wanted to ask, is there any replacement pattern that will fit both of the above situations, i.e. that will generate the correct Url whether the parent is a node or a view/panel.

Comment: I mostly use [node:menu-link:parents:join-path]/[node:title] to have my url aliases the same structure like my menu structure. This might help for your case.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work. The menu-link token does not seem to contain anything when the menu item is created via Node Hierarchy (i.e. the "Show in menu" checkbox is ticked in the Node Hierarchy vertical tab). However, if I also check "Provide a menu link" from the Menu Settings vertical tab, two menu items are created.

Comment: Oh oké, I always build my hierarchy in my menu. My url aliases are the same with the pattern that I suggested. Guess your use case requires another approach then.